# Angular - $watch for $dirty on a form not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to watch for changes to a form using Angular 1.x. I am doing this so that I can display a warning if the user navigates away from the page before saving the data. I am able to $watch for form.$valid just fine, but form.$dirty just never fires. So to be clear, this works:

```
$scope.$watch('forms.editForm.$valid', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // This is how we tell if there are unsaved form changes so we don't navigate away
    $scope.unsavedFormChanges = oldVal;
}, true);
```

And this doesn't:

```
$scope.$watch('forms.editForm.$dirty', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // This is how we tell if there are unsaved form changes so we don't navigate away
    $scope.unsavedFormChanges = oldVal;
}, true);
```

Can anyone please enlighten me as to why I can't $watch $dirty, and if there is a backup plan for doing so? - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head against the wall long enough, I think I've figured this out. It seems to be that $valid is an object, and $dirty is a value. And that's where that third parameter comes in. The "true" at the end of the $watch statement tells $watch what it is watching. True means it's an object, False means it's a value. That being said, this works:

```
$scope.$watch('forms.editForm.$dirty', function (value) {
    // This is how we tell if there are unsaved form changes so we don't navigate away
    $scope.unsavedFormChanges = value;
    $log.info('Form Dirty Changed: ' + value);
}, false);
```

I also changed the oldval/newval to just a value, since that's all we're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the watch to fire reliably on the form $dirty property, so I watched the model for changes instead and then checked the form dirty property like this

```
    $scope.$watch("$scope.data", function () {
        if ($scope.myform.$dirty) $rootScope.pageDirty = true;
    }, true);
```